# why does gsubfn omit part of the match?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, gsubfn

I analyse text strings and I try replace all dots `.` within round brackets `()` with commas `,`

I found a regex that matches eveything within the brackets:

```
text <- "let's count (get . this . without dots) the days?"
brackets = "\\((.*?)\\)"
regmatches(text,regexpr(brackets,text))
```

gives me:

```
[1] "(get . this . without dots)"
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632668/r-regex-match-all-double-quote-characters-inside-square-brackets), I could use `gsubfn` to do the changes:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(brackets, ~ gsub("\\.", ",",x), text)
```

gives me:

```
[1] "let's count get , this , without dots the days?"
```

instead of what I thought I would get:

```
[1] "let's count (get , this , without dots) the days?"
```

Why does gsubfn omit a part of my match? (i.e. the brackets)
Is there any other way the replace the `.` within `()` with `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may keep as many capturing groups as you need in the original regex, no need to modify the pattern, just tell `gsubfn` to use the *whole match* by passing `backref=0` argument:

```
gsubfn("\\((.*?)\\)", ~ gsub("\\.", ",",x), text, backref=0)
[1] "let's count (get , this , without dots) the days?"
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have done here is not to include the paranthesis/brackets within your match. ie You did not capture the brackets. Try

```
text <- "let's count (get . this . without dots) the days?"
brackets = "(\\(.*?\\))" # NOTE THAT I CAPTURED THE PARANTHESIS TOO
regmatches(text,regexpr(brackets,text))
[1] "(get . this . without dots)"


library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(brackets, ~ gsub("\\.", ",",x), text)
[1] "let's count (get , this , without dots) the days?"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using base R `gsub` with positive-look ahead.

```
gsub("\\.(?=[^()]*\\))", ",", text, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "let's count (get , this , without dots) the days?"
```

This matches a dot (`.`) only if the first round brackets to it's right is closing one. `[^()]` matches everything which is not round brackets. The dot is then replaced with comma.